# Application_BeginRequest is not executing

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, iis, httprequest

I am working on an issue from few days. We have a Silverlight application with few links on main page. By default when page loads, content of default link (System) is loaded. Now the problem is with few links, when I navigate to those links, I get Page not available error but when I refresh/reload it works fine.

On investigating I noticed Application_BeginRequest is not firing. I am using integrated pipeline mode in IIS (I can't change it to classic). and in web.config runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests is true.

Below is some part of code from Application_BeginRequest block

```
HttpContextBase httpContext = this.Request.RequestContext.HttpContext;
string requestUri = this.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.ToUpperInvariant();
if (requestUri.Equals("~/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
if (this.Request.QueryString[ConfigurationConstants.queryparam] == null) {
   this.Response.RedirectPermanent("~/System", true);
}
else {
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(ConfigurationConstants.Param, this.Request.QueryString[ConfigurationConstants.queryparam]);
    this.Response.SetCookie(cookie);
    this.Response.RedirectPermanent("~/System", true);
}
  return;
}
// special case: skip processing of requests for specific files
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension)) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pageId)) {
        this.Context.RewritePath("~/Module.aspx", pageId, this.Request.Url.Query);
        return;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Is it a specific http request type (POST? PUT?) BeginRequest isn't fired on?

Comment: Its a GET request... And I noticed one more behavior, if after loading default page, immediately I click on some other link I get that page not available error but if I wait for 15-20 sec and then click on some other link, page is loading.